# Android screen rotation effect when device in locked

Tags: android, rotation, screen, android-lifecycle

I have an Activity with two layouts for landscape and portrait orientation. Everything works fine but! If I will lock a screen by power button, then press power button again, rotate device and unlock, my Activity will be empty. I have checked `onCreate()` method, `onDestroy()` and `onResume()`. If lock a screen and unlock without rotation everything will be ok and only `onResume()` will be called. But if unlock device with screen rotation methods `onDestroy()`, `onCreate()`, `onResume(`), `onResume(`) will called (`onResume()` two times after rotate and after unlock).
I tried to use `android:configChanges="orientation"` - no result. Also I tried `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` it is bad idea because after this activity will use only one layout depend on what orientation app was started

My device is Nexus 7 2013

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the Activity being empty? Empty, as in no layout, or empty, as in no dynamically loaded content (say, a list with items)?

Comment: It looks like setContentView didn't call. Screen just white

Comment: Please share the complete code you have used.